# Weird error: relation <schema name> does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-10

I am running a DDL statement like this in Postgres 11

`ALTER SEQUENCE kwt.VisitReport_seq OWNED BY kwt.VisitReport;`

I am running it as DBADMIN.

Yet I get some weird error:

`SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "kwt" does not exist
  ERROR: relation "kwt" does not exist
  ERROR: relation "kwt" does not exist`

But this is strange... `kwt` is not a relation, it is a schema.

What is going on?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often happens right after posting here I found the problem.

The statement should be:

`ALTER SEQUENCE kwt.VisitReport_seq OWNED BY kwt.VisitReport.ID;`

i.e. it should refer (of course) to the column name, not to the table name.